# Create muliple connections in one query

Tags: neo4j, cypher

How Connect a Node to mulitple Nodes from different type ?
The  nodes to be connected are in a list as parameter , part of the nodes does not exists in the DB . how to connect the exists ones only, witout duplication of alleady exists connection?

```
OPTIONAL MATCH (ja : Course{name: 'Math'}), (jm : Student {name: 'James'}) , (bl : Student {name: 'Bill'})
MERGE (ja)-[r1:learn {nickname: 'ALL'}]->(jm)
MERGE (ja)-[r2:learn {nickname: 'ALL'}]->(bl)
RETURN ja, jm
```

In the above code Student James exists and Bill does not exists
the whole operation failes and the relation between Course (Math ) to Student (James) is not beeing created!

Answer (score 1):

You can do a MATCH across values in a list, and if there are some items in the list for which there is no node, that's fine, as long as at least one works:

```
MATCH (ja : Course{name: 'Math'}), (student:Student)
WHERE student.name IN ['James', 'Bill']
MERGE (ja)-[:learn {nickname:'ALL'}]->(student)
RETURN ja, student
```